# TabControl containing a Ribbon

Tags: .net, wpf, tabcontrol, ribbon

I want to create a Tabcontrol with tabs for e.g. Invoice, Order, Offers,...
As the possible activities differ from Tabitem to Tabitem, I need a RibbonMenu for each Tabcontrol. 
As far as I know, Ribbons don't work properly if they are not directly under a  element.

My question is:
Can I use separate Ribbons in each Tabcontrol?
Would it be better to use just one Ribbon in the Mainwindow and adapt its content to the selected Tab?

Answer (score 0):

Dude, you have to manage user expectations... No application has a tab control with different `RibbonBar`s in each tab... that would just look weird and I don't think that the end users would thank you for it.

Why use the `TabControl` in the first place... the `RibbonBar` *is* an advanced kind of tab control anyway, isn't it? I use one for my current application and it works just fine with different functionality in different tabs. Each tab can have a section to display different views, so you could still have several views per `RibbonBar` tab. The rest of each tab can then be filled with controls that set options or preferences for each section. It works nicely in my opinion.

It's worth noting that these kinds of subjective questions are kind of hard to answer, as there is no one right answer. Also, don't be surprised if the community ends up deleting your question for this very reason.

Comment: Well, my question was kind of if this violates the purpose of the RibbonControl. I need the Tabcontrol to display the different contents of my Invoice / Order /... Documents. I just wanted to adapt the Menubar to the currently selected document.
So the correct way is to use one Ribbonbar and adjust the items of the bar according to the selected Tabitem? (Because I can't place all possible Actions of all Tabs into one menubar)